# How can I change the background color of a ListView's selected item in Xamarin.Forms with iOS 15/16?

Tags: ios, listview, xamarin.forms, background-color, selecteditem

How can I change background color of items of a ListView's selected item in the latest version of Xamarin.Forms for iOS platform?

For old iOS platform, the selected item's background color can be changed by writing a custom ViewCellRenderer:

```
public class ViewCellRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ViewCellRenderer
    {
        public ViewCellRenderer()
        {
        }

        public override UITableViewCell GetCell(Cell item, UITableViewCell reusableCell, UITableView tv)
        {
            UITableViewCell cell = base.GetCell(item, reusableCell, tv);
            ListView listView = cell?.Parent as ListView;
            if (listView != null && listView.SelectionMode == ListViewSelectionMode.None)
            {
                uiCell.SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;
            }
            else
            {
                uiCell.SelectedBackgroundView = new UIView
                {
                    BackgroundColor = ColorCache.ListViewSelectedItemBackgroundColor.ToUIColor()
                };
            }
            
            return cell;
        }
    }
```

But for the latest iOS 15/16, this method does not work again.

Answer (score 0):

After fetching the view structure from Xcode by run the app to the simulator, I found that the new iOS applys the gray background color like this:

`>UITableView->Xamarin_Forms_Platform_iOS_ContextActionCell->UITableViewCellSelectedBackground`

Then you can add a new ListViewRender to override the default selectedBackgroundView's backgroundColor value:

> public class ListViewRenderer :
> Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ListViewRenderer {
> public ListViewRenderer()
> {
> }
>
> ```
> public override void LayoutSubviews()
> {
>     base.LayoutSubviews();
>
>     var controller = this.ViewController as UITableViewController;
>     if (controller != null)
>     {
>         var tableView = controller.TableView;
>         if (tableView != null && tableView.Subviews != null)
>         {
>             tableView.LayoutSubviews();//For lower iOS version, this line must add, otherwise it can not find any UITableViewCell
>
>             var backgroundColor = Color.Red.ToUIColor();
>             foreach (var subview in tableView.Subviews)
>             {
>                 if (subview is UITableViewCell tableViewCell)
>                 {
>                     tableViewCell.SelectedBackgroundView = new UIView
>                     {
>                         BackgroundColor = backgroundColor
>                     };
>                     tableViewCell.MultipleSelectionBackgroundView = new UIView
>                     {
>                         BackgroundColor = backgroundColor
>                     };
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     }
> } }
> ```